# Need to turn off and then turn on the printer for printing

Tags: printing, cups-lpd

I have Kyocera-TASKalfa-1800 connected with my ubuntu server for remote printing.

For printing any file after giving the print command I have to turn off the printer and then turn it on which is irritating me.

**What I have tried:**

Tried to disable and enable cups with following commands:

```
cupsenable Kyocera-TASKalfa-1800
cupsenable Kyocera-TASKalfa-1800
```

Also tried to unbind and then bind the usb, but its not working.

Comment: Question about your server: what sort of machine is it? I’ve seen this in the past where the printer does not get reset to a ready state after a job because an older USB device was not supplying enough power. This was solved by using an externally-powered USB hub to reduce the strain on the host machine and ensure a consistent data stream to the printer.

Comment: It an old cpu with normal hardware

Comment: What is normal hardware mean?